# Undefined reference although symbol present in .so

Tags: c++, linker, ld, undefined-reference, root-framework

Disclaimer: I'm aware of questions like
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526688/i-can-load-functions-from-dynamic-library-with-linking-this-dl-but-i-can-not-lo)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256459/g-undefined-reference-although-symbol-is-present-in-so-file)
but nothing helped me to solve my problem.

I'm trying do compile a larger project dependent on ROOT package, and I was able to reproduce the error I'm facing in minimal example:

test.cpp:

```
#include "Math/GenVector/GenVector_exception.h"
int main()
{
  ROOT::Math::GenVector::Throw("foo");
}
```

compiled with: `g++ -lGenVector test.cpp` gives:

```
/tmp/ccq9A45m.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `ROOT::Math::GenVector::Throw(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

localizing libGenVector.so with `ld --verbose -lGenVector | grep "lib GenVector.so succeeded"` gives:

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libGenVector.so succeeded
```

checking if symbol is defined in library with
`nm -DgC --defined-only /usr/local/lib/libGenVector.so| grep Throw` gives:

```
000000000003f180 T ROOT::Math::Throw(ROOT::Math::GenVector_exception&)
000000000003f1e0 T ROOT::Math::GenVector::Throw(char const*)
```

Basing on answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501207/getting-undefined-reference-error-but-nm-shows-symbol-present), I also tried to compile with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++17` but everything gives the same error message.

Comment: Order matters! If source, object file or library `A` depends on library `B`, then `A` must come before `B` on the command line.

Comment: oh, great, and I see `g++ test.cpp -lGenVector` works! thanks, @Someprogrammerdude, if you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: In practice (not related to what was the problem), with root I found it more useful to check the rootmap files before checking the contents of .so files for a sort of human readable lookup "which so should I link against to use which class" (doesn't come with dependencies though).

Comment: And, for the c++ standards, I would use `root-config --cflags` rather than guessing `-std=c++1?` - I expect troubles to surface once you build projects depending on root with a different c++ standard version than the one root got built with.